# Plotting the results of a Newton-Raphson solution for multiple cases

Tags: matlab, plot, numerical-methods, angle, newtons-method

Consider the following problem:

[image]

I am now in the third part of this question. I wrote the vectorial loop equations (`q=teta2`, `x=teta3` and `y=teta4`):

```
fval(1,1) = r2*cos(q)+r3*cos(x)-r4*cos(y)-r1;
fval(2,1) = r2*sin(q)+r3*sin(x)-r4*sin(y);
```

I have these 2 functions, and all variables except `x` and `y` are given. I found the roots with help of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InIkxZcz7YI&t=857s&ab_channel=MATLABProgrammingforNumericalComputation).

Now I need to plot graphs of `q` versus `x` and `q` versus `y` when `q` is at `[0,2pi]` with delta q of 2.5 degree. What should I do to plot the graphs?

Below is my attempt so far:

```
function [fval,jac] = lorenzSystem(X)

%Define variables
x = X(1);
y = X(2);
q = pi/2;

r2 = 15
r3 = 50
r4 = 45
r1 = 40

%Define f(x)
fval(1,1)=r2*cos(q)+r3*cos(x)-r4*cos(y)-r1;
fval(2,1)=r2*sin(q)+r3*sin(x)-r4*sin(y);

%Define Jacobian
 jac = [-r3*sin(X(1)), r4*sin(X(2));
     r3*cos(X(1)), -r4*cos(X(2))];

%% Multivariate NR

%Initial conditions:
X0 = [0.5;1];
maxIter = 50;
tolX = 1e-6;

X = X0;
Xold = X0;
for i = 1:maxIter
    [f,j] = lorenzSystem(X);
    X = X - inv(j)*f;

    err(:,i) = abs(X-Xold);
    Xold = X;
    if (err(:,i)<tolX)
        break;
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you post the code/attempt you have so far? It might help us understand what exactly you're trying to plot.

Comment: What is the input `X`? Do you have an illustration of the expected result?

Comment: I add picture of the question.

Comment: It's a good addition, but doesn't answer my question :( Do you know what the _q vs x_ and _q vs y_ charts should look like? What is the relation between the input to the function, `X`, and the illustration you just added?

Comment: Sorry about that. I forget to answer your question. I do not know what should the charts looks like exactly. But it is like, change of value of teta2 will change the other two angles. I think the graphs looks like sunisiodal waves but i m not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at my solution below, and study how it differs from your own.

```matlab
function [th2,th3,th4] = q65270276()
[th2,th3,th4] = lorenzSystem();

hF = figure(); hAx = axes(hF);
plot(hAx, deg2rad(th2), deg2rad(th3), deg2rad(th2), deg2rad(th4)); 
xlabel(hAx, '\theta_2')
xticks(hAx, 0:pi/3:2*pi);
xticklabels(hAx, {'$0$','$\frac{\pi}{3}$','$\frac{2\pi}{3}$','$\pi$','$\frac{4\pi}{3}$','$\frac{5\pi}{3}$','$2\pi$'});
hAx.TickLabelInterpreter = 'latex';
yticks(hAx, 0:pi/6:pi);
yticklabels(hAx, {'$0$','$\frac{\pi}{6}$','$\frac{\pi}{3}$','$\frac{\pi}{2}$','$\frac{2\pi}{3}$','$\frac{5\pi}{6}$','$\pi$'});
set(hAx, 'XLim', [0 2*pi], 'YLim', [0 pi], 'FontSize', 16);
grid(hAx, 'on');
legend(hAx, '\theta_3', '\theta_4')
end

function [th2,th3,th4] = lorenzSystem()
th2 = (0:2.5:360).';
[th3,th4] = deal(zeros(size(th2)));

% Define geometry:
r1 = 40;
r2 = 15;
r3 = 50;
r4 = 45;

% Define the residual:
res = @(q,X)[r2*cosd(q)+r3*cosd(X(1))-r4*cosd(X(2))-r1; ... Δx=0
             r2*sind(q)+r3*sind(X(1))-r4*sind(X(2))];     % Δy=0

% Define the Jacobian:
J = @(X)[-r3*sind(X(1)),  r4*sind(X(2));
          r3*cosd(X(1)), -r4*cosd(X(2))];

X0 = [acosd((45^2-25^2-50^2)/(-2*25*50)); 180-acosd((50^2-25^2-45^2)/(-2*25*45))]; % Accurate guess
maxIter = 500;
tolX = 1e-6;

for idx = 1:numel(th2)
  X = X0;
  Xold = X0;
  err = zeros(maxIter, 1); % Preallocation
  for it = 1:maxIter
    % Update the guess
    f = res( th2(idx), Xold );
    X = Xold - J(Xold) \ f;
%     X = X - pinv(J(X)) * res( q(idx), X ); % May help when J(X) is close to singular
    
    % Determine convergence
    err(it) = (X-Xold).' * (X-Xold);
    if err(it) < tolX
      break
    end
    % Update history
    Xold = X;    
  end
  
  % Unpack and store θ₃, θ₄
  th3(idx) = X(1);
  th4(idx) = X(2);
  
  % Update X0 for faster convergence of the next case:
  X0 = X;
end

end
```

Several notes:

1. All computations are performed in degrees.
2. The specific plotting code I used is less interesting, what matters is that I defined all `θ₂` in advance, then looped over them to find `θ₃` and `θ₄` (without recursion, as was done in your own implementation).
3. The initial guess (actually, analytical solution) for the very first case (`θ₂=0`) can be found by solving the problem manually (i.e. "on paper") using the law of [cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines). The solver also works for other guesses, but you might need to increase `maxIter`. Also, for certain guesses (e.g. `X(1)==X(2)`), the Jacobian is ill-conditioned, in which case you can use [`pinv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html).
4. If my computation is correct, this is the result:

[image]